# CSV format file generated from a template, how to prevent Safari on Mac downloading as html file?

Tags: csv

I have an Exp Eng template that generate a .csv format file using a channel tag. I also insert the headers of the file using php, as shown below (those are the fist lines of the template). In Firefox the file downloads with a simple click on a link to the template and everything seems fine.

```
<?php 
header("content-type: text/csv");
header("content-disposition: attachment; filename=filename.csv");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Cache-Control: private");
header("Expires: 0");
```

It all seems to be working but Safari on the Mac will insist on downloading it with an .html extension as in 'filename.csv.html'. I've researched this on the Internet at many say it is just a peculiarity with Safari. But another person accessing the file says it happens no matter what browser they are using.

In Exp Eng I have the template settings as an "html" template. The other choices don't seem to work, like RSS/feed, and static would disable the channel tag. Any ideas on how to get around this problem?

Thanks,
Bob.

Answer (score 1):

Per this [**StackOverflow answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1465573/forcing-to-download-a-file-using-php), try adding the following to your .htaccess file:

```
AddType application/octet-stream .csv
```

Also, try changing your Content-Type header code to:

```
header('Content-Type: application/csv');
```

Comment: I tried these suggestions out and made these changes and the csv files download in other browsers as files as intended. But Safari still adds the '.html' on the end of the file name, even with these changes. I'm inclined to believe this is an issue only with Safari.

Comment: Is it possible it's a browser caching issue? What's the URL? I'll test it here.

Comment: Just for kicks... try changing the name of the CSV file as a test.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the data you want to export, you might be able to accomplish your goal with the [AJW Export](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/ajw-export) plugin. Could be worth looking at if you haven't already.

Comment: I did look at this already but it seems to only use an SQL query. I needed to format the data also and combine fields.

Answer (score 0):

try next header:

```
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=filename.csv');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
header('Cache-control: no-cache, pre-check=0, post-check=0');
header('Cache-control: private');
header('Pragma: private');
header('Expires: 0');c
```